# Running Grunt from OSX Automator shell script

Tags: macos, bash, shell, automator

I have a simple Gruntfile that I want to be able to run from an icon in my OSX dock.

I have created a very simple shell script (launcher.sh) that I will save as an application so I can add it to my dock. It works great when I run it directly in my Terminal:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
$(grunt serve --open)
```

It also works fine with this shebang: `#!/bin/bash`

However when I call the shell script from an Automator workflow I get the following error:

```
launcher.sh: line 2: grunt: command not found
```

This is my Automator set up:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Update**

If I put this in my `launcher.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
`/usr/local/bin/grunt serve --open`
```

I get a different error in Automator: `env: node: No such file or directory`

But, as before, if I run the script directly in Terminal its fine - so I think @mklement0 is right about the `PATH`

**Update 2**

launcher.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
grunt serve --open
```

Automator

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
~/Public/Sites/launcher.sh
```

Now I'm still getting an error popup when I run it in Automator, but it has no details - it just says:

```
The action "Run Shell Script" encountered an error.
```

The Log panel shows a blank entry. Is there a way to get more info? A verbose mode perhaps?

**Update 3**

So this is weird... if I use `&> ~/log` it works. Without it it fails.

But this is working, thanks @mklement0, it'll do for now

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
cd ~/Public/Sites && ./launcher.sh &> ~/log
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the `$PATH` variable when running from Automator doesn't have the same entries as when running from Terminal.

Notably, `/usr/local/bin` is missing, which is where `grunt` is typically installed (if installed *globally*).

A simple workaround is to add the folder in which `grunt` is installed to your `$PATH` at the top of the Automator shell script:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
~/Public/Sites/Launcher.sh
```

---

Aside from that:

- Your shell command, `$(grunt serve --open)`, should be just `grunt serve --open` - no need for a command substitution (`$(...)` or `` `...` ``), as that would actually first execute the command *and* then try to execute the *output* from that command.
- The default working dir. when running a shell script from Automator is `~` (your home folder), which may not be what your script expects; it looks like your script expects its own dir. to be the working dir., so use `cd ~/Public/Sites && ./launcher.sh` to invoke it.
- Automator will report an error in case the shell script exits with a *nonzero* exit code; the error message will include the shell script's *stderr* output (and nothing else) - sounds like no stderr output is being produced in your case.

  - To capture *all* output for diagnostic purposes, use something like `./launcher.sh &> ~/log`

---

On macOS 10.11 through at least 10.15 (as of this update), `$PATH` has the following value inside a shell script run from an Automator workflow: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`